# Caching array requests - Lazy Loading

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a bunch of JSON files that I need to send through the wire. Each file is quite big, and I need to load them on demand.

My server serves the files dynamically, and it allows array gets too (to minimize http requests).

So that means if I need Json file `[1, 2, 3, 4, 16, 17, 32]`, it makes an ajax request to the server with that array and I get all those JSON.

Now from my understanding caching is done per request. That means if my application needs Json File `1` again, it will make a new request instead of the cached version since it's a different request from my first.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you get the data by making a request per file instead of one for all of them?  That would allow the browser to cache it the way you'd expect (as long as you set the appropriate headers).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a central 'module' that will deal with sending the requests to the back-end. There you can store a registry (or a simple array) which will store the files that that had already been fetched; This way you can decide whether to make the request or not.

From what i understood, the array that you send to the back-end contains the identifiers of some JSON files that the server can locate. If that is the case, store those id's in your central module e.g. `dataservice` and make the checks before you make any further requests

```
IF jsonToFetch in jsonCache
THEN 
    return
ELSE 
   make the request
   ADD jsonToFetch to jsonCache
```

Answer (score 0):

In such situation you can't rely on any built-in caching mechanism, so you have to write your own caching code. Something like this may work:

```
var cache = {};

var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty

function notCached (file) {
  return !hasOwnProperty.call(cache, file);
}

function cached (file) {
  return cache[file];
}

function getFiles (files, callback) {
  var filesToRequest = arr.filter(notCached);

  //make real http request
  if (filesToRequest.length) {
    makeRequest(filesToRequest, _callback);
  } else {
    process.nextTick(getFromCache);
  }

  function _callback (err, files) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    //cache files
    filesToRequest.forEach(function (file, i) {
      cache[file] = files[i];
    });

    getFromCache();
  }

  function getFromCache () {
    callback(null, files.map(getFromCache));
  }
}
```

Here you basically deduce files absent in cache and request only them. Of course, using object as a cache storage has some disadvantages, so you can make some asynchronous interface for that and implement it with `fs` or leveldb or whatever you like.